# Disassembly of the .rodata section for global variables in C++ (objdump -D)

Tags: c++, x86-64, disassembly, objdump

I am looking to better understand assembly instructions pertaining to C++. I have written a simple .cc file to try to reverse engineer it, but I am having trouble understanding what is going on. Ultimately, I want to gain more insight into what is executed before main is called in the realm of global variables.

How are `y1` and `y2` variables initialized? What is the assembly doing?

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

struct y {int i; int j;};

const y y1{7,2}, y2{6,4};

int k = 9;

int jy = k;

int main() {}
```

Here's the generated disassembly from `objdump -D`:

```
00000000004007e4 <_ZL2y1>:
  4007e4:   07                      (bad)
  4007e5:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  4007e7:   00 02                   add    %al,(%rdx)
  4007e9:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    ...

00000000004007ec <_ZL2y2>:
  4007ec:   06                      (bad)
  4007ed:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  4007ef:   00 04 00                add    %al,(%rax,%rax,1)
    ...
```

Comment: This isn't code and it doesn't make sense to disassemble it.  It's just the bytes `07 00 00 00 02 00 00 00` in memory, which are the two little-endian `int`s 7 and 2 that are the two members of `y1`.

Comment: Looks like you are disasembling the data section of the application. Those are not instructions that is raw data.

Comment: I was using objdump -D <binary>. It greatly confused me until commenter below clarified.

Answer (score 4):

The variables are initialized by *static initialization*, meaning before any code (necessarily) executes. The implementation accomplishes this by storing the memory image in the compiled binary.

Look at the hexadecimal values: they match the numbers you assigned in the initializations. Those aren't instructions at all. The disassembler just printed `add` out of ignorance.

Comment: `The disassembler just printed add out of ignorance.` cracked me up haha

Comment: On the topic of static initialization, the jy variable in my example is NOT statically initialized? Because it depends on the k variable? (I see assembly instructions initializing it before main and it is located in the .bss section). Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Good question! No, it's not, but the compiler is anyway free to optimize away those instructions as if it were.

Comment: It's not exactly ignorance.  Those are the instructions the CPU would execute if you used `mprotect` to make that page executable and jumped there.  Like you would for testing shellcode;  `objdump -D` is only useful when you do care about interpreting data in other sections as machine code.  (Or as a quick hack if you want to look at the hexdump part and ignore the disassembly).

Comment: @PeterCordes aha, I didn't notice that `-D` forces disassembly for all sections whereas `-d` is the more common option.

Comment: Yeah, OP only mentioned that in a comment.  Even `const` globals will go in `.rodata` or `.rdata`, which is a separate section from `.text`, which is why this isn't normally a problem.  (`objdump -d` would print empty output for the OP's file that has no functions.  Or maybe an iostream constructor or something.)